# yiic - can't run - env: php\r: No such file or directory

Tags: php, yii

On MAC OS X Lion - Running MAMP

I'm trying to execute the following yiic command (from Yii framework);

```
./yiic message ./app/messages/config.php
```

I'm getting this message:

> *env: php\r: No such file or directory*

I've looked into yiic file and I see:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/yiic.php');
```

I've looked into /usr/bin/env

and I see, nothing related to php (I believe):
Should I have there something related with php ?

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/qq/4k5m37mn16bgfpp6yt8ggljc0000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-L43tVY/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=299
TERM_SESSION_ID=1999B4D4-939B-4065-B71C-D9B0563A9EC6
USER=mem
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-FBmmga/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
PWD=/usr/bin
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/mem
LOGNAME=mem
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-oXxXFl/org.x:0
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/usr
```

As anyone add this error before?

Is this something to do with the fact that php is not on that env think perhaps?

Please advice

Comment: I tried to add yiic and php.exe to my windows environment variables to not have such problems, but that didn't work. Calling yiic and php.exe with absolute paths was the more simple solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read [this](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/10/31/getting-started-with-the-yii-framework/) blog: could be the very same problem you are experiencing?

> The next step is to tell the yiic application, found in the framework folder, to create a new site. The syntax is
>   yiic webapp path/to/directory
>
> But before you even begin to use this command, let me explain it a bit, as it’s very important and can be complicated. The yiic file is an executable that runs using the computer’s command-line PHP and that really just invokes the yiic.php script. You may be able to call it using just yiic or using ./yiic (i.e., run the yiic command found in the current directory). Or you can more explicitly call either script using php yiic or php yiic.php. Or you may need to indicate the PHP executable to be used: C:\php\php.exe yiic. You should try the variations on this command, as applicable to your computer, just to make sure you can invoke yiic, prior to trying to create the Web application.

Comment: Brilliant post that I couldn't found. That was indeed my issue. Running:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php yiic message ./app/messages/config.php solved.

Comment: In my case, installing the package `php5-cli` helped.

Answer (score 3):

It looks you're just experiencing an encoding issue with your yiic file. The shell is trying to use php\r interpreter to open yiic, instead of php.

Run the following command to replace all CARRIAGE_RETURN characters by LINE_FEED :

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r/\n/g' yiic.php
```

Worked pretty well in my case.

Comment: I had same issue, or better said I continuously have this issue because Net Beans always converts line endings to Windows format on my machine

Answer (score 0):

In my case that worked for using xampp:

Creating new project:

```
X:\xampp\php>php.exe X:/xampp/htdocs/yii/framework/yiic webapp X:/xampp/htdocs/YOUR_PROJECT
```

yiic shell:

```
X:\xampp\php>php.exe X:/xampp/htdocs/YOUR_PROJECT/protected/yiic shell X:/xampp/htdocs/YOUR_PROJECT/index.php
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer sorry. :( Are you suggesting to do what exactly ? thanks.

Comment: try to call yiic directly with absolute paths, like i did show you for calling yiic shell or yiic webapp

Answer (score 0):

Just I [changed php version](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693) of my system form 4 to 7.
I run this command to salve this issue-

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue as i was using xampp server in ubuntu os the yii framework is actually looking for the php bin folder instead of directly installing the php-cli the following solution will help you .
first thing you need to do is to navigate to the folder where you have Extracted the yii folder contents,suppose the folder is htdocs then

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/yiifolder/framewok
```

next thing you need to do is to paste the following command

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php ./yiic webapp ../your project name
```